# Posting a link in Telegram which opens the Instagram app on iOS

Tags: ios, instagram, telegram, deep-linking

Up until about a month ago, I could have my Telegram Bot send the message `"instagram://user?username=userName"` and if clicked, it would open the Instagram app on  userName's profile on iOS. Now it just appears as unclickable text.

Is there another way to do this now or have Telegram removed this functioality?